# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Auth' not found

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana, php, mysql

Версия Kohana 3.3

Имеем таблицу users с полями id, nickname, mail, avatar, pass

Также есть форма в виде с полями nickname, mail, pass - посылаются они POST'ом.

В контроллере делаю примерно следующее:

```
$nickname = $this->request->post('nickname');
$mail = $this->request->post('mail');
$password = $this->request->post('pass');

$user = ORM::factory('User');
$user->nickname = $nickname;
$user->save();
```

Вылетает еррор:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Auth' not found
```

В чем проблема, и причем здесь Auth? Я его нигде не использую и в bootstrap его не подключал. Пишу регистрацию и авторизацию своими средствами, без использования средств коханы.

Comment: На какой из этих строчек вылетает?

Comment: Вот всё, что выдает дебаггер:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/evc0a6aqgpfnl8c/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.PNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не странное поведение, это называется "предопределённый класс". Придумайте другое название и/или расширьте класс User.

Update
С префиксом model_ в 3.3
Проверяйте структуру

Comment: В смысле класс модели Model_User?

Comment: $nickname = $this->request->post('nickname');
$mail = $this->request->post('mail');
$password = $this->request->post('pass');

$user = ORM::factory('User');
$user->nickname = $nickname;
$user->save();

Можно и нужно заменить на:
$user = ORM::factory('User');
$user->values($this->request->post(), array('nickname', 'mail', 'pass');

а 
$user->save();

"обернуть" в конструкцию try/catch

Comment: >> В смысле класс модели Model_User?
ага

Comment: @kemerov4anin Да нет, всё же странное. Кохана должна брать из папки Application приоритетнее, чем из System или Modules. На прошлых версиях таких проблем не было. В итоге это единственное решение выходит?

Comment: Вообще, логично излагаете. Но вот Model_User наследует не Model, а Auth.

Comment: @kemerov4anin И всё равно, должно наследовать то, что указанно в классе в Application :) Да и хрен бы с ним, только вот на что переименовать юзер модель то?)

Comment: Расширяем указанную модель и всё. Никто не мешает и не запрещает этого делать

Comment: Ну, или, наследуем Model, а не Auth и костылим и велосипедим с авторизацией

Comment: Ладно, придумаю что-нибудь, хоть буду знать причину, спасибо :)

UPD: @kemerov4anin Хотя подождите. Есть таблица posts, есть модель Model_Post.php с содержимым class Model_Post extends ORM {} в папке Model в application. Пробую из контроллера либо так: ORM::factory('Post'), либо вот так: new Model_Post(). И в обоих случаях получаю это: ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Post' not found. Может просто у меня модели не подхватываются по какой-то причине?